# How can I delete LRU folders until 5GB free space is available?

Tags: powershell, file-io, directory, lru, delete-directory

Given a folder, say  `\\localhost\c$\work\`.

I'd like to run a powershell script every 15 minutes that ensures 5GB of free space is available.

If < 5GB is available, remove the least recently used folder within work until >5GB is available.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule the task, you can use the task scheduler ([example here](http://get-admin.com/blog/?p=4))

For a script you could use

```
param($WorkDirectory = 'c:\work'
    , $LogFile = 'c:\work\deletelog.txt' )

#Check to see if there is enough free space
if ( ( (Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = 'C:'").FreeSpace / 1GB ) -lt 5)
{
    #Get a list of the folders in the work directory
    $FoldersInWorkDirectory = @(Get-ChildItem $WorkDirectory | Where-Object {$_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]} | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending)
    $FolderCount = 0

    while ( ( (Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = 'C:'").FreeSpace / 1GB ) -lt 5)
    {
            #Remove the directory and attendant files and log the deletion
        Remove-Item -Path $FoldersInWorkDirectory[$FolderCount].FullName -Recurse
            "$(Get-Date) Deleted $($FoldersInWorkDirectory[$FolderCount].FullName)" | Out-File -Append $LogFile

            $FolderCount++
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that all depends on how your folders are "used". If there are no easy indicators you can try using the .NET [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class to look for changes and remember them as well as a timestamp in a queue, ordered by access time. Then you can pick the next folder to delete from that queue. But it's certainly not pretty.